# php html select value

Tags: php, html

I have a select box connect to database for countries, it works but trying to keep the selected data in the form clears itself out. I have tried adding a selected but gives error

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label>Country</label>
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM countries ";
        $result = query($sql);
        ?>
        <select class="form-control input-lg box" id="country"  name="country">
                        <option value="">Select a country</option>                      
        <?php
        $i = 0;
        while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) != false) {
            ?>
        <option value="<?=$row["country_id"];?>"><?=$row["country_name"];?></option>
        <?php
            $i ++;
        }
        ?>        
        </select>
                </div>
```

Comment: Show us the code where you added  selected. It should be something like <option value="<?=$row["country_id"];?>" <?php if($row["country_id"]==$selectedvalue) echo 'selected'; ?> > <?=$row["country_name"];?></option>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the return value of a ternary operator to the variable $selected and add it to the option tag

```
<?php
    $selected = ($_POST['country'] == $row["country_id"])?"selected":"";
?>
<option value="<?=$row["country_id"];?>" <?=$selected ?>>
    <?=$row["country_name"];?>
</option>
```